# Ubuntu disco is not supported

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ubuntu-19.04

I am trying to install hyperledger composer but I am getting the error
Error: Ubuntu disco is not supported

I am using ubuntu 19. I have also tried to add bionic in the array. but does not work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLzTG.png)

Answer (score 0):

@Syed Ahmed Ali Shah

Hyperledger Composer is deprecated try to avoid it as much as you can

Trt to use the traditional way of creating chaincode and deploy to peers by

- install
- instantiate

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, hyperledger composer is deprecated so there will be no further updates/help to it. It is recommended that you focus on the hyperledger fabric programming models and hyperledger fabric itself. A good starting point is here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/getting_started.html

You can still continue to use hyperledger composer for education purposes if you wish.

In your case have you tried adding `disco` to the array of ubuntu version names ? It may work. Or you could install ubuntu 16.04 or even ubuntu 18.04 (and add bionic to the list). ALternatively don't use the script and install the pre-reqs manually yourself as described in the composer documentation.